# How to get a ajax call with get request not throwing erros

Tags: ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call on the below url

```
http://postalpincode.in/api/postoffice/tindivanam
```

which works fine with chrome address bar.

but if i use

```
 city  = 'Tindivanam';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://postalpincode.in/api/postoffice/'+_.toLower(city),
    method: 'GET',
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
})
```

I am getting this

[image]

Comment: This API doesn't support CORS so you cant access it from client side js. You have to make the api call from a server side script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: I understand the CORS issue. But the call is a GET call and works fine on chrome window.  In general get calls should get the html content as it is likely scraping the window. Correct me please.